# Iterating over controls in wxPython in order to save session data

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a GUI written in wxPython (with boa constructor). 
I would like to save a user's session to a file, to be loaded the next time the application starts. 
I would like to avoid saving each value 'by hand' by iterating over the controls and saving their values to a dictionary.

Is there a way to get a hold of all the wxIDs used in the application, and their corresponding widgets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the IDs at all, just start from the top level window and recursively enumerate all the children using [wxWindow::GetChildren()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ad500085ad0511879b5e018706c91a494) method. Then, for each child, you will need to dynamically determine its type (this is simpler if you only use controls of a few types) and save its value. You may also find it useful to specify the *names* (not labels) for your controls when creating them to have a more convenient unique identifier for each of them than a numeric ID.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you are going at this wrong.  The state of a user's session is best not stored in the values of the controls.  The state should be stored in a 'model'.  The 'view' should query the model when it needs to display the state of the model, and when it wants to save the state to a file.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.

This makes lots of things easier, even trivial, including your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the PersistenceManager mechanism in wx.lib.agw. Here are the original docs for it: http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/AGW_Docs/persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html

And here are the newer docs:

https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html#wx.lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager

Alternatively, you can probably use the frame or panel's GetChildren() method to grab all the widgets and pull the values from them, but I think the PersistenceManager would make more sense.

Comment: The wxpython.org links are dead.
Try: https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager.html#wx.lib.agw.persist.persistencemanager.PersistenceManager

Comment: Good catch. I added a newer link as you suggested